# Puppeteer on Raspberry Pi fails to start chromium-browser: Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: raspberry-pi, puppeteer, chromium

I am trying to run puppeteer on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu installed.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function configureBrowser() {

    // error here
    var browser1 = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser', args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('www.google.com');
    return page;
 }

async function monitor() {
   let page = await configureBrowser();
}


monitor().catch(error => { console.error("Something bad happened...", error); });
```

It produces the error below from the chromium-browser. Does anyone know what this means? I have tried installing extra dependencies and various options for the browser launch, but nothing yet works. It is a Raspberry Pi 4 that I ssh into.

```
(node:2870) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Something bad happened... ErrorEvent {
  target:
   WebSocket {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] { open: [Function], error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
     _closeCode: 1006,
     _closeFrameReceived: false,
     _closeFrameSent: false,
     _closeMessage: '',
     _closeTimer: null,
     _extensions: {},
     _protocol: '',
     _readyState: 3,
     _receiver: null,
     _sender: null,
     _socket: null,
     _bufferedAmount: 0,
     _isServer: false,
     _redirects: 0,
     _url:
      'ws://127.0.0.1:35593/devtools/browser/b4694718-7829-4f29-945a-1a16d20455a8',
     _req: null },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'read ECONNRESET',
  error:
   { Error: read ECONNRESET
       at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read' } }
```

Comment: Having the same few times per day on remote server